# E-Mail redirect from DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, redirect

Honestly I do not how to format this clearly as possible, but my problem is shortly said that if I have a VPS or any server, but I do not want to run mail server on it, though this server hosts my-domain.com, how can I make so that another service handles all the e-mails I receive from email@my-domain.com. Should this be done from the name servers to which the domain point, if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed do that in DNS, with the [`MX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) record.

The MX record  exists specifically to instruct mailservers which host(s) handles mail for a host or domain. That allows you to set for instance that email for `@example.com` is handled by the server `smtp.example.co.uk` and not by the host with the `example.com` `A` record.

It is not quite a redirect, as the host the MX records points at needs to be explicitly configured to accept mail for `@example.com.`

In a Bind style zone file that would look like:

```
@        IN  MX 10   mail.example.co.uk.
```